# Subtracting each element of A from every element of B

Tags: matlab, vectorization, octave

Suppose I have two matrices A and B where:
A is 100x2
B is 5x2

I want to subtract each element of A by every element in B. I can run the following to get to achieve what I want:

```
for j = 1:5
    D = A - B(j, :);
    C = [C(:,:); D(:,:)];
end;
```

However this is slow with huge matrices. All my attempts to vectorize this is met with an error of "nonconformant arguments"

```
j = 1:5;
C = A - B(j, :);
```

How can I condense the above for loop to make use of vectorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might help you:

```
arrayfun(@(x) x*B, A, 'Uni', 0)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried bsxfun to no avail, but this works!

Answer (score 2):

[Permute axes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html), use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) for broadcasted subtractions, [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) to `2D` -

```
reshape(bsxfun(@minus, permute(A,[1,3,2]), permute(B,[3,1,2])),[],2)
```

With `implicit-broadcasting/implicit-expansion` -

```
reshape(permute(A,[1,3,2]) - permute(B,[3,1,2]),[],2)
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     1     2
     4     8
>> B
B =
     3     2
     5     6

% Original loopy code
>> C = [];  
for j = 1:size(B,1)
    D = bsxfun(@minus, A, B(j, :));
    C = [C(:,:); D(:,:)];
end;
>> C
C =
    -2     0
     1     6
    -4    -4
    -1     2

% Proposed code
>> reshape(bsxfun(@minus, permute(A,[1,3,2]), permute(B,[3,1,2])),[],2)
ans =
    -2     0
     1     6
    -4    -4
    -1     2
```